# Master and Slaves issue

Tags: mysql, replication

I have one master and 2 slaves,one is replicating but another slave which is read-only not replicating.

From Master :

show master status;
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |                                                                                    |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| mysql-bin.002490 | 13000479 |              |                  | 
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Slave : Master has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for more updates

Slave status:

```
Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
     Master_Host: ....
              Master_User: repl
              Master_Port: 3306
            Connect_Retry: 60
          Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.002490
      Read_Master_Log_Pos: 13106512
           Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000018
            Relay_Log_Pos: 13106725
    Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.002490
         Slave_IO_Running: Yes
        Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
               Last_Errno: 0
               Last_Error: 
             Skip_Counter: 0
      Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 13106512
          Relay_Log_Space: 13107019
          Until_Condition: None
           Until_Log_File: 
            Until_Log_Pos: 0
       Master_SSL_Allowed: No
    Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
  Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
```

slave processlist show below for system user

i. Waiting for master to send event
ii.Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates

Still not replicating.what i have to check ?

Any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look like everything is fine. Why do you think there is still no replication?

Comment: Everything seems to be fine. Try onething to ensure replication is running that create one table on master & check same on both slave

Comment: I have created database on master but not replicating, tried 3/4 times.

Comment: Replication not happening on above slave (details given in question) and in other slave replication happening.

Comment: If slaves behave differently then they differently configured.

Comment: Generally above configuration is fine right for any slave ? Any other thing i have to check, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

These say that it is replicating:

```
     Slave_IO_Running: Yes
    Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
           Last_Errno: 0
           Last_Error: 

Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
```

Check my.cnf on both the Master and Slave -- look for replicate/binlog_do/ignore_...  Perhaps you are not allowing some databases or tables to go from (`do`) the Master or be received by (`ignore`) the Slave.

The various `%read_only` variables control whether or not you can connect to the server and write; *replicated* writes are always allowed on the Slave.